# IValueConverter - Casting generic Collections

Tags: c#, generics, collections, casting, ivalueconverter

I want to create a type independent Converter for counting the elements in a collection with a generic type.

```
    public class CollectionCountConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((SomeCastingType)value).Count;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); // not used for oneway binding
    }
}
```

value in this case is a Collection of any type. The problem is to find the correct casting type and cast the object. What I want to have is something like

```
Type t = value.GetType();
ICollection<t> c = (ICollection<t>) value;
int count = c.Count();
```

but this does not work. I also tried to use Object as generic type, but then I get an InvalidCastException. Is there any elegant way to do it?

Comment: What is the *actual* type involved here? Most collections implement the nongeneric `ICollection` interface as well, which makes things simpler... could you use that instead?

Comment: You could also use `IEnumerable<object>`. This is where `Count()` is declared.

Comment: The actual Type of the list is **List<AnyClass>** and it is working with the ICollection interface casting! Sorry, I am new to c# ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) is covariant, you can use this.

```
return ((System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>)value).Count();
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx):

> Type Parameters
>
> out T
>
> The type of objects to enumerate.
>
> This **type parameter is covariant**. That is, you can use either the type
> you specified or any type that is more derived.